# Ruby on Rails 5.2.0 Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError SSL connection error: unknown error number

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, backend

I am new to RoR, but not new to web development in general.
I am trying to switch a Rails app from **sqlite3** to **mysql2**, it is api-only.
Added the gem to **Gemfile**, used **bundle install**, everything fine.
I run **rails server** and see the error bellow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX4Gm.jpg

[image]

This is my **Database.yml**:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  username: root
  password: 123456
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: beginner_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: beginner_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: beginner_prod
```

Comment: Hi @C. Gabriel, try removing `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock` this live from database.yml and try again.

Answer (score 8):

I succeeded to solve the problem by adding the following lines to **database.yml**, default **section**:

```
ssl_mode: :disabled
sslverify: false
```

The error isn't so descriptive, but apparently it was related to ssl.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `database.yml` content with the following configs

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  username: root
  password: 123456

development:
  <<: *default
  database: beginner_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: beginner_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: beginner_prod
```